# How to simulate a mouse click while another app is in focus (python preferably)

Tags: python, automation

I'm looking for a way to simulate a mouse click on a secondary monitor while my first monitor is in focus. I've tried multiple different strategies and library's but nothing is working.

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

def control_click(x, y, handle, button='left'):

l_param = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

if button == 'left':
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)

elif button == 'right':
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, l_param)
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, l_param)

control_click(100,100,"Edit1")
```

This is the code that I got from another stack overflow answer but it also doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the resolution of the monitor let's say 1366 x 768, Python always takes the left corner of the First Monitor for x and y as (0,0) so the code can be altered simply by adding the coordinates to your def.

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

def control_click(x, y, handle, button):

l_param = win32api.MAKELONG(x+1366, y+768)

if button == 'left':
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)

elif button == 'right':
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, l_param)
win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, l_param)

control_click(100,100,"Edit1","Left")
```

Please do let us know if this solution helps

Comment: It didn't work for me, I'm on VSCode if that affects anything and just to clarify I'm testing on notepad right now. I'm just trying to simulate a mouse click on a different screen while keeping my mouse somewhere else unaffected.